# A rest element must be last in a tuple type

Tags: typescript, types, type-definition

When writing type for `cb`:

```
const fn1 = (
  cb: (...args: [...args: any[], fn2: () => string, fn3: () => string]) => any,
  ...args: any[]
) => {
  const fn2 = () => 'fn2'
  const fn3 = () => 'fn3'
  cb(...args, fn2, fn3)
}
```

Run `tsc`, an error is thrown:

```
A rest element must be last in a tuple type.
```

Comment: This would be a good use case for the better “rest” tuple  typing in TS4.2: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-2/#non-trailing-rests

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVnaxN) what you're looking for?  It's hard to tell without some examples for what you want to be able to do inside and outside the function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out I was using the global `tsc` the whole time, which was `v3.2.9`, no wonder I had behaviors different from other people's. When I switched to the local `tsc` which was `v4.2.3`, the code was compiled successfully.

Comment: when i run tsc -v i get `Version 4.2.3` yet when tsc it runs fine when i run `npm run build` which executes `tsc; cp package.json ./lib/src/package.json` i get `A rest element must be last in a tuple type.` Npm update fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error says move, "...(boolean | ExpressionInputType | ExpressionSpecification)[]" element at last position

```
"case",
        boolean | ExpressionSpecification,
        ...(boolean | ExpressionInputType | ExpressionSpecification)[],
        ExpressionInputType | ExpressionSpecification,
        ExpressionInputType | ExpressionSpecification,
    ]
```

Like this

```
"case",
        boolean | ExpressionSpecification,
        ExpressionInputType | ExpressionSpecification,
        ExpressionInputType | ExpressionSpecification,
        ...(boolean | ExpressionInputType | ExpressionSpecification)[],
    ]
```